# Spring Sleuth Do not generate Trace Id and span Id and not communicating with Zipkin server

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am trying to test spring cloud Zipkin.
When I make a request to this API, it is not not generating Tracking ID or Span ID.
Any idea what am I missing?

My Pom Dependencies

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.tracing</groupId>
<artifactId>Zipkin-Server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Zipkin-Server</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My Application Properties

```
spring.application.name=sample-tracing
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=DEBUG
spring.zipkin.baseUrl: https://localhost:9411/
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage=1.0
```

My Controller

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class HelloController {
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello() {
    log.info("Enter the Hellow World Controller");
    return "Hello world";
}}
```

The Logs:

````
2022-12-15T13:24:15.514-05:00  INFO [sample-tracing,,] 10220 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.tracing.zs.controller.HelloController  : Enter the Hellow World Controller
2022-12-15T13:24:15.516-05:00 DEBUG [sample-tracing,,] 10220 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud Sleuth does not work with Spring Boot 3.0. You have to migrate to Micrometer Tracing - read more here https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide